# How to avoid chaining parameter as input and output in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, reactivex

I don't have solid concepts on ReactiveX yet. What I'm trying to do is to download new files from an FTP server.

The sequence that I'm currently thinking of is connect -> list files from FTP -> filter out files that are already in local path -> download new files.

How to do this on a ReactiveX way, without having to pass the FTP connection as a parameter and returning it as an output for the next operator?

I don't think having something like this is the correct way:

```kotlin
fun listFilesFromFTP(ftpConnection : Connection) : Pair<Connection, List<Files>>

connectionObservable.flapMap(::listFilesFromFTP).flapMap(::filterLocalFiles).flatMap(::downloadFiles)  ... and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in a pure functional way, without depending any data other than the function parameters, then you can define a FileDownloadContext with all connection and file info in it. Then all your functions can receive FileDownloadContext, edits it and then pass to the next function.

Or you can do it in a stateful way via encapsulating those functions in a class. So functions can reach to the class state. This is similar to Closure concept. Of course for each new file download request you need to create an new state object not to mix states.